# XPATH last element that have specific element

Tags: xml, xpath, dtd

Given this DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT root (t*)>
<!ELEMENT t (pay|gift)?>
<!ELEMENT pay EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST pay amount CDATA #IMPLIED >
<!ELEMENT gift (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST gift amount CDATA #REQUIRED >
```

how can I reach by XPATH query the amount of the last gift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
(//gift)[last()]/@amount
```